# Python - Remove a specific after a specific character?

Tags: python, string, character

How do i remove a specific after a specific charactor or value in the string?

My string looks like:

Name: 33 KG: 5.0 Name: 19 KG: 404.0 Name: 93 KG: 17.0

I would like it to look like:

```
Name33 KG:5 Name19 KG:404 Name93 KG:17
```

I need to remove the : and the space behind Name, I would also like to remove the . and the 0 behind KG

The problem is i don't want to remove all the spaces : and all the 0

Comment: Use regex with string.replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> pattern = re.compile(
...     "(?<=\:)"   # Look for :
...     " "         # Match space
...     "([0-9]+)"  # Number to keep \1
...     "(?:\.0)?") # Optional .0
>>> pattern.sub("\\1", "Name: 33 KG: 5.0 Name: 19 KG: 424.0 Name: 93 KG: 17.0")
'Name:33 KG:5 Name:19 KG:424 Name:93 KG:17'
```